# Как узнать что сообщение доставлено(spring websocket stomp sockjs)?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, sockjs

Использую client-server приложение с коммуникацией через WebSocket.
На сервере пользуюсь спринговским SimpMessagingTemplate:

```
Map<String, String> ackHeader = new HashMap<String, String>();
ackHeader.put("id", ""+System.nanoTime());
Map<String, Object> ackHeaders = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ackHeaders.put(StompHeaderAccessor.STOMP_ACK_HEADER, ackHeader);
template.convertAndSend(clientDestination, ьуыыфпу, ackHeaders);
```

Мой WebSocketConfig:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/client");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/endpoint").withSockJS();
}
```

Если клиент закрыл броузер, как мне это понять при вызове метода convertAndSend или еще каким-то способом - может какой-то handler повесить, вопрос как и куда?